# Socket connection using public IP on iPhone

Tags: ios, sockets, websocket, p2p, wifip2p

I'm having a requirement to connect my iPhone device with a tool(developed using python) via socket connection. Both the devices will be connected to a same wifi, I need to open a socket as a server using my public IP (ex. 192.168.166.168), which I will pass to the tool, and it will try and connect using the same with same port. I cannot use any AWS or 3rd party server, it has to be using public IP. I've tried many demos but can't somehow create a socket server using public IP. Any suggestions would be a great help, as I am totally new to socket programming.

So far I've tried using Starscream library to initiate the socket using a server, which works, but I do not want that, as I want communication to happen between 2 devices on same wifi without any web server involved.

My code using StarScream :

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "wss://socketsbay.com/wss/v2/\(deviceID)/demo/")!)
request.timeoutInterval = 100
socket = WebSocket(request: request)
socket.delegate = self
socket.connect()
```

Reference link to the lib : https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream

Comment: 192.168.x.x. are *private* IP addresses, but I assume what you mean is you want to listen for a connection on the phone's assigned Wifi IP address.  You should [edit] your question to show the code you are using to listen for an incoming connection.

Comment: Thank you for the response, yes so actually confused about the IP, and so far I've tried https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/creating-websocket-server-on-ios-using/ and https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream but no luck.

Comment: You will need to use the [Network](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network) framework on iOS to listen for incoming connections. Note that this framework can't listen for websocket connections, but you can use a TCP connection